docker-compose service cannot connect to other services in docker-compose
I have spring-boot app that uses DB, i have defined the docker-compose file for the it:
services:
  my-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      DB_HOST: app-db
      DB_PORT: 5434
      DB_USER: myuser
      DB_PASSWORD: mypassword
      DB_NAME: mydb
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: my-app
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    volumes:
      - production_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db/create_script.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_script.sql
    ports:
      - "5434:5432"
    container_name: app-db
volumes:
  production_data:

and application.properties:
# Database connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

However, when i run the docker compose, the my-app containers fails on the error:

>      HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
>     java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException,
> String)" because the return value of
> "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()"
> is null


Which pretty much means it cannot connect to the database, if u omit my app from docker-compose file and just starts the DB from it, it works ( with changed DB_HOST to localhost ).
What is causing this? As they are defined in docker-compose, they should be in the same network ( and by inspecting the containers, they indeed are in the same network created by docker-compose)
Thanks for help!

The problem is that you have:
DB_PORT: 5434

But postgres is listening on port 5432. Port publishing (mapping container ports to host ports) does not impact container-to-container communication; it only effects how ports are exposed on your host.
If your backend database is only used by your application, there's no reason to publish the database ports on the host.
